# How to synchronize onMessage() of MessageListener

Tags: spring, jms, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I have a spring3 web application.I use org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer to configure my message listener.I have a MDPOJO registered. What I wanted is, when onMessage() is getting executed for a particular request,others should wait until the first one finishes.In other words, onMessage() method invokes further work flow and it would take time to finish it off.Other messages in the queue should not be picked by onMessage until it confirms that previous request is complete.

Does it possible to synchronize the processing onMessage().I need to do the following :

1. Users will be posting n number of message into the Queue
2. I should be having an interface where user can remove a message from the queue.
3. When one message is under process, any of the other messages should not be picked up.
4. User should be able to change the priority of message processing

Comment: Do you really need to use JMS and message queues ? If so, maybe you'd try to configure only one consumer of the queue (ie `setConcurrentConsumers(1)`)

Comment: Fine. Now I have to monitor JBoss Queue programatically. Is it possible to track the status of JBoss queue using java code? I may have to delete certain messages which I do not want to get processed. As well I need to change the priority of processing. I tried different mechanism. I tried the way in http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?tag=jms . But seems not working

Comment: The monitoring of a JMS queue is platform dependant. What's the version of the JBoss Messaging that you are using ?

Comment: I am using the default along with jboss-5.1.0.GA

Answer (score 0):

I could programatically list the messages in the queue using below code :

```
public void listAllJMS_Messages() 
    {
        try {
            ObjectName objectName=new ObjectName("jboss.messaging.destination:name=DLQ,service=Queue");
            List ls = (List) server.invoke(objectName, "listAllMessages" , null, null);
            List<javax.jms.Message> messages=(List<javax.jms.Message>)server.invoke(objectName, "listAllMessages" , null, null);
            int count=0;
            for(javax.jms.Message msg : messages) {
                System.out.println((++count)+"t"+msg.getJMSMessageID());
               if(msg.getJMSType() != null && msg.getJMSType().equalsIgnoreCase("Text")) {
                TextMessage text = (TextMessage)msg; 
                System.out.println(text.getText());
               }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        // System.out.println((++count)+"t"+msg.getText());
    }
```

But the above code list messages from those Queue which do not have any consumers so far.My case I have an MDPOJO as message consumer which processes message synchronously. Still I want list messages from the Queue, so that user can delete it if he wishes.Above code return null list in case I have a consumer of the queue.

Comment: The management API is described here : http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/usermanual-2.0.0.beta4/html/management.html. It contains some samples too.

Comment: I went through the doc.Still I could not find a solution.I am wondering is there is a way to monitor a JBoss Messaging queue which is currently under use.Things working fine, when my Queue does not have a consumer at all.If i have a consumer, then only messgaeCount works properly.Listing message return null

Comment: Have you tried through a JMX client (JConsole for instance) ? If you can list and remove messages from the JMX client, you could do it programmatically.

Comment: I tried through JMX console.I tried with http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/ by clicking listAllMessages, it returns null despite messageCount is 3. Have a look at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBMESSAGING-1729  . seems it may not list messege if there is a message consumer at present

Comment: Do you really need to use a JMS provider ? Would a simple ConcurrentHashMap do the job ?

Comment: I solved the problem,I added below attribute to connection-factories-services.xml file :  <attribute name="PrefetchSize">1</attribute> , which ensure that only one message is picked up by the message consumer at a time.By default this value is 150,